# eclipse pydev outline doesn't handle pyx files from cython very well

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev, cython

I am just getting started experimenting with Cython and I renamed one of my source files from .py to .pyx and built it with Cython and MSVC 2008 on 64-bit Windows 7. It compiled fine and my code runs fine. But when I try to open the pyx file in Eclipse (4.2.0) with Pydev (2.7.1), the outline view does not work at all. Rather than having all my classes separate like usual, with all their methods nicely packed under each class definition, it just lists all classes and methods sequentially, as if they're all at the base-level indentation. This is extremely annoying as I have grown dependent on the outline view to navigate my code. There's no folding/collapsing, filtering, or anything! What can I do? Thanks.

Update: Pydev 3.4.1 has additional cython support and shows the file slightly better in Eclipse. [Here's the relevant blog post](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2014/03/pydev-341-improved-interactive-console.html). Filtering works in the outline, but folding still doesn't.

Comment: Having the same issues here... :(

Comment: PyDev was designed for Python, in the first place. Not Cython...